# The small error probability P for a dataset

Tags: time-series, arima, fourier-transform

P = $p\{\frac{|\epsilon(k)-\bar{\epsilon}|}{S_1} < 0.6745\}$

Say we want to calculate the probability shown in the formula above.

I have the values for all $\epsilon$ parameters and $S_1$. Therefore both the sides will have a magnitude.

How can I calculate a probability if both sides of the "less than" sign has a magnitude.

This is a common formula used to verify the forecasting accuracy in ARIMA modeling. What does the formula to the left of the "less than" sign mean?

Comment: Thank you for improving your question. I replaced the picture by Mathjax code because it is easier to search for users.